# ¿Es recomendable usar cookies para un carrito online?

Tags: php

¿Es recomendable usar cookies para un carrito on-line? Hasta el momento estoy usando variables de sesión, pero cuando cierro el navegador se destruye tanto la sesión como los artículos que agregué al carrito.

Comment: Yo veo dos soluciones para ello. 1: las coockies y la mas eficiente por mi punto de vista. 2: por bbdd, poniendole al usuario como una tabla carro. Yo uso coockies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema del uso de las *cookies* es que puedes guardar hasta 4kB de datos, además de eso encuentro que la información de lo que tus clientes quieren comprar deberías guardarla de forma persistente (aunque no confirmen la compra al final), ya que esto te puede servir mucho para realizar un posterior análisis.

Me imagino que para una aplicacion web como la tuya existe un *log in*, en ese caso en mi opinión una buena solución seria:

- Usar variables de sesión para manejar el carrito de compras de un usuario anónimo (que no ha iniciado sesión y simplemente esta visitando tu pagina web)
- Una vez hecho el *sign in* ir guardando estos datos en una base de datos.